How to add precise collider with simulate physics enabled in Unreal Engine
I have bolt and nut models as below

Is it possible in UnrealEngine to

add precision collider to match both the bold and nut surface to enable screw animation
enable "simulate physics" function so once the nut is unscrewing, it falls due to gravity


I'm not saying it's impossible, but I would instead fake it. If you want this to "feel real" e.g. for a VR then you can totally do it, by faking it. When the bolt is "inserted" correctly into the nut (or vice versa), it would be easier to just lock their positions together and make the rotation move them along each other to get the desired result. And if you do that, you can use your detection algorithm the other way around to re-enable regular physics on the nut when it is no longer connected to the bolt.
